# how to use contacts from people app in our own application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am working with phonegap on windows phone 8 .In my app I have to pick contacts from emulator and I can use that contact in my app(data should be send to that number).but I'm unable to do this.I have tried contact picker which is for windows 8 on visual studio 2013 but still I am not getting how to implement that in code or suppose I have to call that contact picker app in my own app how should I do?.Because I'm working on visual studio 2012 and that app is in visual studio 2013 .And if not possible tell me the others way to do this so that I can select contacts from the people app or from emulator and can use in my application.And again one question can I use the php for server side code in phonegap.For validating server side data.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap has nothing to do with windows 8, it's platform agnostic, you can use whatever server tech you wish, you need to use JS / HTML for phonegap

Answer (score 0):

You can use contact cordova plugin here.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts